# Unable to use customer class asp.net core post method [FromBody] attribute

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

In my asp.net core web api project, when I try to an entity/model using post method, its failing.

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddDeviceController([FromBody] DeviceController controller)
        {
            if (controller == null) return GetActionResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "DeviceController cannot be null");
            return GetActionResult(service.AddDeviceController(null, null, null), HttpMethod.Post);
        }
```

Here DeviceController model exists in a seperate assembly.
**If I copy this model code to the web api service, it works perfectly!** However, it fails to load when I refer it from the Models project. In this case, I receive `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`exception with an error message `Cannot load assembly C:\\3_SourceCode\mywebPI\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\MywebApi.Models.dll`

**Please help me to get over this.**

Answer (score 0):

Check for the dll in the dependencies and in bin.

Comment: All such checks are done. Get method uses the same and it works perfectly.